# Groovy - Get shortname of the month in German

Tags: datetime, groovy, monthcalendar

I try to get the short name of the month in groovy, but in German... (Jan, Feb, Mrz, Apr...)

I can get it in English with the simple statement:

```
mydate='2012-11-23 02:26:55.983'
origDate=new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.S',mydate).format('MMM')
```

but in german ?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

String mydate = '2012-03-23 02:26:55.983'

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( 'MMM', Locale.GERMANY )

assert sdf.format( Date.parse( 'yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.S', mydate ) ) == 'Mrz'
```

Longer example:

```
def months = new SimpleDateFormat( 'MMM', Locale.GERMANY ).with { sdf ->
  (1..12).collect { month ->
    sdf.format( Date.parse( 'MM', "$month" ) )
  }
}
println months
```

prints:

```
[Jan, Feb, Mrz, Apr, Mai, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Okt, Nov, Dez]
```

Comment: gee, great tim. Thanks very much.

Comment: @laloune No worries :-)  If it worked, can you accept this answer as accepted? (there should be a tick next to it somewhere)  Good luck and have fun! :-)